# Do 2 of the same circles contain each other? (Proving / Disproving)

Tags: geometry, circles, fake-proofs

Two Circles, $C_1$ and $C_2$ have the same center $(h, k)$ and radius $r$.

Trying to prove or disprove that $C_1$ contains $C_2$ and $C_2$ contains $C_1$ OR neither contains the other.. but I think I'm leaning towards the former by this logic:

A Circle $A$ is contained in a circle $B \iff \forall \; (x, y) \in A$, $(x, y)$ is also $\in B$.
Or in other words, every point in B is less than A's radius from A's Center.

So for the case where $A$ and $B$, are geometrically identical:
The distance from $A$'s center to $B$'s center is $0$, therefore any point in $B$ is at most $A$'s radius away from $B$'s center (aka $B$'s radius, so within $B$).

Another approach might hint at the Ship of Theseus. Since $A$ and $B$ are geometrically identical, $B$ can be replaced with $A$. and $A$ contains itself. Therefore $A$ contains $B$, and $B$ contains $A$ by the same logic.

Does this hold water? I started by thinking about counting intersections but that sent me down the wrong rabbit hole I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately depends on how formal you want to be, but your first approach feels vague, and the second feels circular (in that it somewhat assumes $A=B$ from the outset).

I would approach it in a more set-theoretic fashion.

You seem to have defined two sets, your circles, by the following rules:

$$\begin{align*}
S_A &:= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\middle|\, 0 \le \sqrt{|x-h|^2 + |y-k|^2} < r  \right\} \\
S_B &:= \left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \,\middle|\, 0 \le \sqrt{|x-h|^2 + |y-k|^2} < r  \right\} 
\end{align*}$$

Notice how both have encoded that, for $(x,y)$ to be contained in the circle, its distance from $(h,k)$ must be less than $r$. (Possibly including $r$ depending on your definition, but it won't affect things.)

Then that $S_A \subseteq S_B$ and $S_B \subseteq S_A$ is immediate ($(x,y) \in S_A$ iff it meets the distance condition, which is the same in $S_B$), and so $S_A = S_B$.

Comment: Thanks I really appreciate the approach of thinking of it as a set of points.
I guess I was okay with assuming A = B from the outset, but the question would remain, if A does = B, then that means they do in fact, contain each-other? In the set notation its much clearer, since we're not worried about "strict" subsetting

Comment: For something to contain another thing, you need to clarify what that actually ***means.*** Set-theoretic ideas, i.e. set inclusion, is the most natural way to define that in this situation, and seems to be in the vein of what you're looking to use. In that case, equality of sets, i.e. $S=T$, is literally defined by inclusion in each other, i.e.

$$S = T \stackrel{\text{def.}}{\iff} S \subseteq T \text{ and } T \subseteq S$$